# Why does this query raise an exception?

Tags: 8, database

I am using the following code to query an ECK entity.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('object__field_amount', 'f');
$query->fields('f', array('object__field_amount_value'));
$query->addExpression('MAX(object__field_amount_value)', 'maxvalue');
$query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

It raises the following exception.

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxvalue FROM object__field_amount f'

I've tried multiple other options, without result.

How do I avoid the code raises an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MAXVALUE` is [a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL (Maria). Change `maxvalue` to `topvalue` or something else.

Comment: Yes, MAXVALUE is the issue here. I think you can remove the "looks like". :-)

Comment: Dear god, this was it, would have probably never found it myself. Thanks!